# Want to fetch outlook mails from the oldest mail to the newest mail using python

Tags: python, outlook

What I'm doing here is fetching emails from outlook using python. The problem is its getting random emails while fetching. What I want is to fetch emails in a sorted manner from the oldest to the newest emails so that I can store it to any database in a well-structured form(more helpful if any logic that will extract datewise from the oldest to the newest in one loop.). Any help will be appreciated.

```
def emailleri_al(folder):
    messages = folder.Items  ## want to add logic here
    for message2 in messages:
        Subject=message2.Subject
        print(Subject)        
for account in accounts:
    if account.DisplayName=="mymail@gmail.com":

        global inbox
        inbox = outlook.Folders(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)

        folders = inbox.Folders

        for f in folders:
            emailleri_al(f)

print("Finished Successfully")
```

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: win32com.client,
 win32com,
 os,
 sys,
 datetime,
from datetime import date    MAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", false)` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort

Comment: Thanks for the help, but can u help me a little more like in Gmails we get Ids for each mail-in bytes, Through these ids, I can get to know the track of emails that are fetched. Outlook something is there through which  I can have a track so that I can continue fetching from that particular email whenever I want to continue.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but you might want to post a new separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea in Outlook. Instead, I'd suggest extract items in chunks by using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. You can read more about these methods in the following series of articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

The `Restrict` method is an alternative to using the `Find` method or `FindNext` method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The `Find` or `FindNext` methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The `Restrict` method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.

For example, a sample code listed in C# shows to use the `Restrict` method:

```
private void RestrictCalendarItems(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
    DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,
                                  DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 00, 00);
    string restrictCriteria = "[Start]<=\"" + dtEnd.ToString("g") + "\"" +
                              " AND [End]>=\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + "\"";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
    Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
    Outlook.Items resultItems = null;
    Outlook._AppointmentItem appItem = null;
    int counter = default(int);
    object item = null;
    try
    {
        strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        folderItems = folder.Items;
        folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
        folderItems.Sort("[Start]");
        resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
        item = resultItems.GetFirst();
        do
        {
           if (item != null)
           {
               if (item is Outlook._AppointmentItem)
               {
                   counter++;
                   appItem = item as Outlook._AppointmentItem;
                   strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() +
                                         "\tStart: " + appItem.Start.ToString() +
                                         "\tSubject: " + appItem.Subject +
                                         "\tLocation: " + appItem.Location);
               }
               Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
               item = resultItems.GetNext();
           }
       }
       while (item != null);
       if (strBuilder.Length > 0)
           Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
       else
           Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the "
                            + folder.Name + " folder.");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
       if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
       if (resultItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItems);
   }
}
```

So, you can process ordered items for a small timeslot.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar requirement: I needed to list all email with a specific subject in the order they were received - then later pick the latest one. I used a python library called exchangelib.

Here is the python snippet to do it:

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')**[:100]**: **#for your requirement you just need to remove [:100]**
    print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)

and here is the full code with step by step explanation.

https://medium.com/@theamazingexposure/accessing-shared-mailbox-using-exchangelib-python-f020e71a96ab

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but i figured it out!